# How do you leave Erebus?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I started playing with the Erebus mod, but a big question is unanswered: How do I leave the Erebus dimension?

Comment: Should be closed, as we do not support questions regarding mods.

Comment: @JosephStalin Yes we do. What we don't support is *tech support* for modded Minecraft. This question (presumably) has a definitive and correct answer that people who are familiar with this particular mod can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kim and Duncan from the Yogscast have explored the Erebus dimension during their current series.

What you need to do is go back to the place where you entered the Erebus dimension and use the Erebus key on that portal in the same way as you did to open it in the overworld.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIWSr_9-1aQ&t=21m6s) shows how they do it, starting at 21:06.

Comment: (embedding <strike>with a timestamp</strike> is hard... I give up)

Comment: The problem is that no return portal was generated, I guess that means I have to just build another portal the same way as the portal to the erebus?

Comment: @kutschkem Could you show a picture of the location you spawned into the Ere)bus dimension? According to earlier in that linked video (around 15:55), you spawn on top of a  multiblock structure that mimics the Erebus portal on the other side, but without the erebus key plugged in.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs See https://github.com/ganymedes01/ErebusIssueTracker/issues/42 for a description of what I think happened. For now, I teleported back to Overworld with a Warp book I had, and reentered the Erebus to see if it spawns a portal. Now a portal is there, although for some reason it is floating high in the air.

Comment: @kutschkem That link is dead.

Comment: @pppery Thanks, I have no clue what it used to say and didn't find the issue somewhere else. Here is a link to a different issue that also says no return portal was generated: https://github.com/vadis365/TheErebus/issues/663