# Configuring QuiverBow's Arms Assistant

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am trying to make the Arms Assistant from the QuiverBow Mod ignore my PortalGun Sentry turret. However I don't know what to put in the writable book, the documentation is not very extensive...

Here is what I tried:

- craft Book and Quill
- write "Sentry Turret" in it
- give it to the Arms assistant
- give a weapon to Arms assistant

Result: it attacks the sentries.

What am I doing wrong here? I tried also "PortalTurret", which is the name of the Sentry turret item (I think not of the entity), but that didn't work either.

I would appreciate an answer that is general enough that it allows me and other people to apply it to any kind of entity that needs to be blacklisted.

Comment: Technically, Arqade doesn't provide help for Modded Minecraft.

Comment: According to a comment to my last question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227666/how-do-you-leave-erebus, Arqade does - just not for technical problems. This is a question that can clearly be answered by someone who knows how to configure the thing. It's about mod content.

Answer (score -1):

Try naming the sentry turret with a nametag or in an anvil, then put that name in the book.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. It seems you're unsure whether your own solution works. This isn't a great thing to have in an answer. If you do have real knowledge about whether this works, it would be a good idea to present that.